# How to make History command to record the userid, timestamp, ip address and command

Tags: bash

We have a server being visited all the time. I want to record the userid, ip address and commands being executed. Please kindly tell me how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're really looking for auditing. A few quick pointers:

- [For Linux](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/)
- [For FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/audit.html)

Basically, these frameworks can be configured to log every command executed, including the arguments given, etc.